# Use VBA to delete OR highlight rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a code that solves the following criteria: 
If a specific cell in column C equals zero, delete row
If a specific cell in column U STARTS with 9, delete row
If a specific cell in Column E is a negative value, delete row
If a specific cell in column C starts with 2015, highlight color
If a specific cell in column C starts with 2016, highlight same color as above
If a specific cell in column C starts with 2017, highlight with different color
All else, leave

This is what I have so far and I keep getting coding errors.
I know this is very specific, any help is greatly appreciated

Sub Module()

```
Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Set sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

With Worksheets(sSheetName)
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then .EntireRow.Delete
        If Left(Cells(x, 21), 1) = 9 Then .EntireRow.Delete
        If Left(Cells(x, 5), 1) = "-" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        If Left(Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6017 Then
            cell.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        If Left(Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6018 Then
            cell.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        If Left(Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6150 Then
            cell.Offset(, -6).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Which errors do you get? Use `.Cells` instead of `Cells`. Is `cell` a variable or a typo?

Comment: What is wrong with the code?  Where specifically does it break down and what error is being displayed?

Comment: What is `sSheetName`? You haven't defined it.  Probably a string - in that case remove the `set` when assigning the name of the sheet.

Comment: Also, within the scope of your `With` `.EntireRow.Delete` isn't valid. You need e.g. `.Cells(x,3).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Compile Error that I am getting:

Block If without End If

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum up all the comments:

```
Sub Module()

Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

With Worksheets(sSheetName)
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then .Rows(x).Delete
        If Left(.Cells(x, 21), 1) = 9 Then .Rows(x).Delete
        If Left(.Cells(x, 5), 1) = "-" Then .Rows(x).Delete
        If Left(.Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6017 Then
            .Cells(x,1).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        ElseIf Left(.Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6018 Then
            .Cells(x,1).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        ElseIf Left(.Cells(x, 3), 4) = 6150 Then
            .Cells(x,1).Resize(, 21).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        Else
            .Cells(x,1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next x
End with
End Sub
```

Comment: This either needs some line continuation characters (`_`) or some `End If`s.

Comment: @SteveLovell but I needed to take out the space in `ElseIf`

Comment: Dang! You're right. Still needs the `End With` though! Sorry.

Comment: Why do we have 6017, 6018 and 6150 ? Should these be 2015, 2016 and 2017 ?

Comment: @SteveLovell IDK, I just copied what the OP had in their code.

Comment: Saw that just after I posted. Looks weird. Since it's a string at that point (due to `left(x,4)` I'd naturally put quotes round it too. Not sure what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored code, this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rDelete As Range
    Dim rPurple39 As Range
    Dim rGreen43 As Range
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("1:" & lLastRow).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        For i = 1 To lLastRow
            If .Cells(i, "C").Value = 0 _
            Or Left(.Cells(i, "U").Value, 1) = 9 _
            Or Left(.Cells(i, "E").Value, 1) = "-" Then
                If rDelete Is Nothing Then Set rDelete = .Rows(i) Else Set rDelete = Union(rDelete, .Rows(i))
            Else
                Select Case Left(.Cells(i, "C"), 4)
                    Case 6017, 6018:    If rPurple39 Is Nothing Then Set rPurple39 = .Cells(i, "A") Else Set rPurple39 = Union(rPurple39, .Cells(i, "A"))
                    Case 6150:          If rGreen43 Is Nothing Then Set rGreen43 = .Cells(i, "A") Else Set rGreen43 = Union(rGreen43, .Cells(i, "A"))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    If Not rPurple39 Is Nothing Then rPurple39.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    If Not rGreen43 Is Nothing Then rGreen43.Interior.ColorIndex = 43

End Sub
```